# How to make tool tips with quotation marks inside in HTML?

Tags: html, tooltip

The following piece of HTML code:

```
   <span title="Download this file to your computer">
   <a href="URL">
   <img src="SomeOtherURL" alt="Download" style="width:42px;height:22px;border:0">
   </a></span>
```

works fine unless my title has no quotation marks in it .

However, when it does:

```
<span title="Download "Shanghai Surprise" to your computer">
<a href="URL">
<img src="SomeOtherURL" alt="Download" style="width:42px;height:22px;border:0">
</a></span>
```

then everything collapses. Is there any way to do tool tips with quotation marks inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the HTML escape character instead:

```
&#34;
```

or

```
&quot;
```

example:

```
&#34;word&#34; or  &quot;word&quot;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Lonebop/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot use an attribute value delimiter, here the Ascii quote ("), inside the attribute value as such, for obvious reasons. There are several ways around this, but the most natural one is to use *correct* quotation marks in the text. The Ascii quotes are not correct quotes in English text, or in human languages in general; use proper “double” or ‘single’ quotes, depending on the version and style of English of your preference. Using common US style:

```
<span title="Download “Shanghai Surprise” to your computer">
```

The proper English quotes are just data in HTML, with no special role as delimiters or otherwise.

Comment: "The Ascii quotes are not correct quotes in English text, or in human languages in general" - Why not?

Comment: @brilliant, consult any style guide on English, or whatever language you are using.